# How can I convert this piece of code to Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have this Java 6 code which I'd like to convert to Java 8.

```
BigDecimal sumContributionPercentage = new BigDecimal(0);                   
if (hasElements(mandateDetails)) {
  for (InstrumentMandateDetail mandate: mandateDetails) {
    if(!(VERFI_STATUS_CLOSED.equals(mandate.getMandateVerificationStatusType().getCode()) ||
         VERFI_STATUS_REJECTED.equals(mandate.getMandateVerificationStatusType().getCode()))) {
      sumContributionPercentage = sumContributionPercentage.add(mandate.getContributionPercentage());
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `getContributionPercentage()` returns a `BigDecimal`, you can use the following :

```
BigDecimal sumContributionPercentage = 
    mandateDetails.stream()
                  .filter(m -> !(VERFI_STATUS_CLOSED.equals(m.getMandateVerificationStatusType().getCode()) || 
                                 VERFI_STATUS_REJECTED.equals(m.getMandateVerificationStatusType().getCode())))
                  .map(InstrumentMandateDetail::getContributionPercentage)
                  .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```